# How do I add a conditional form field through content projection in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add a conditional field through content projection.

The projected input field is toggling correctly in accordance to its sibling checkbox field. When the checkbox is "checked" the conditional field displays. When the checkbox is "unchecked", the input field disappears.

However, when I move the checkbox into its "checked" state, I'm receiving an error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'detail'
```

I want the projected `detail` field to be apart of the `_formGroup` in the child component, not the parent component. How can I achieve this?

The error seems to suggest that the `formControlName="detail"` is not visible to the `_formGroup` in the child component. How can I rectify this?

Here is the parent component with the outer parent Form Group.

**Parent Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ch-parent-comp',
  templateUrl: './parent-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-comp.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor() { 

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        //detail: new FormControl('') --> Adding this will solve the issue, but I don't want this field here. I want it in the child 
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**Parent Component HTML Template**

```html
<form>
    <ch-check-box-group [parentFormGroup]="formGroup" controlName="new_property" controlLabel="New Property" [hasDetail]="true" [detailRequired]="true">
        <!-- Projected Input Field -->
        <ng-template contentHandle>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Purchase Date</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput name="detail" formControlName="detail" id="">
            </mat-form-field>
        </ng-template>
    </ch-check-box-group>
</form>
```

**Child Component(ch-check-box-group)**

```js
export interface CheckboxGroupForm {
  value: FormControl<boolean>,
  detail?: FormControl<any>
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ch-check-box-group',
  templateUrl: './check-box-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./check-box-group.component.scss']
})
export class CheckBoxGroupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private _ks: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  _formGroup: FormGroup
  _showDetailInput: boolean = false;

  @Input() controlLabel!: string;
  @Input() controlName!: string;
  @Input() parentFormGroup!: FormGroup;
  @Input() hasDetail: boolean = false;
  @Input() detailRequired: boolean = false;

  @ContentChild(ContentHandleDirective) content!: ContentHandleDirective;



  constructor() { 
    this._formGroup = new FormGroup<CheckboxGroupForm>({
      value : new FormControl(false, {nonNullable: true}),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.hasDetail){
      this._formGroup.addControl('detail', new FormControl(''));
    }
    this.parentFormGroup.addControl(this.controlName, this._formGroup);
    this._formGroup.setParent(this.parentFormGroup);


    this._formGroup.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._ks))
      .subscribe((change) => {

        // Toggle visibility of detail input
        if(this.hasDetail && this._showDetailInput != change.value){
          this._showDetailInput = change.value;
        }

        // Toggle Validation(if necessary) of detail input
        if(this.hasDetail && this.detailRequired && change.value){
          setTimeout(() => {
            this._formGroup.get('detail')?.addValidators(Validators.required);
          });
        } else {
          this._formGroup.get('detail')?.clearValidators();
          if(this._showDetailInput != change.value){
            this._formGroup.get('detail')?.updateValueAndValidity();
          }
        }

        console.log(this._formGroup.controls)


        
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this._ks.next();
    this._ks.complete();
  }

}
```

**Child Component Template**

```html
<div class="row">
    <form class="col-12" [formGroup]="_formGroup">
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="value" i18n>{{ controlLabel }}</mat-checkbox>
        <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
            <mat-icon>help</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div class="conditional-input-box-container" *ngIf="_showDetailInput">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content.templateRef"></ng-container>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, pass the child components `_formGroup` to the `[ngTemplateOutletContext]` like so:

```html
<div class="row">
    <form class="col-12" [formGroup]="_formGroup">
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="value" i18n>{{ controlLabel }}</mat-checkbox>
        <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
            <mat-icon>help</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div class="conditional-input-box-container" *ngIf="_showDetailInput">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content.templateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: _formGroup}"></ng-container>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then use that new variable in the parent component like this:

```html
<form>
    <ch-check-box-group [parentFormGroup]="formGroup" controlName="new_property" controlLabel="New Property" [hasDetail]="true" [detailRequired]="true">
        <!-- Projected Input Field -->
        <ng-template contentHandle let-_formGroup>
           <div [formGroup]="_formGroup">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Purchase Date</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput name="detail" formControlName="detail" id="">
            </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ch-check-box-group>
</form>
```